# Global querystring parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to add functionality to an existing AngularJS application. I need to be able to pass an additional parameter to potentially any route of the angular application. (It's an email tracking ID)

I would like to use a querystring parameter if it's possible, without affecting the existing routing. Then have some code somewhere that checks for the querystring parameter (not sure about this part, some kind of global navigation listener?).

I'm not super familiar with angular. Do i need to mess with the routing and mess with code in the controllers, or is there some way I can code one global service to parse the querystring parameter regardless of the route?

I know I could create a service that uses `$location` to get the querystring parameter, but I would have to inject that service into every controller which seems kind of redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an email tracking id I'm assuming that you just need to grab it once when the user first enters the site. It also looks like you're not looking for a super deep solution, so I'd suggest just grabbing it where the main module (your app) is first created and storing the tracking id as a property on your app.

Comment: yeah, your assumptions are correct. I just want to grab the tracking ID parameter (if it exists) when the user first hits the site. I don't want to alter the existing routes if possible. I'll look into this approach.

Comment: If your app has an app.run you can add the code there, if it doesn't you can safely add an app.run method to your main js file that does this. Just add app.run as a separate line after you main module and config, etc. are created.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the suggestion. I think this is the route I'm going to take. I'm hoping that additional parameter doesn't interfere with any of the existing routing!

Comment: Ok, so seems to work. I am injecting $location into  app.run and I can use $location.search() from there. The additional querystring parameter does not appear to affect the existing angular routing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` event that fires on the `$rootScope` that you can bind to in a run block somewhere if you want to grab a query string from the route every time the page changes.

But if you're trying to keep track of that value throughout your entire application, once you get it from the server, you could store it on a service and inject it wherever you need it in your application. If you're trying to avoid injecting dependencies into your Angular app, then you're only going to hurt yourself, especially when it comes time to write tests. Your controllers shouldn't depend on things that aren't provided through your application's injector.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$location`. It adds hashed query string params like "example.com/#?myParam=value"

Get query string params:

```
$location.search(); // gives you an object of params
```

Set query string params

```
$location.search('myParam', 'value'); // one at a time
$location.search({ // or pass an object
     'first':1,
     'second':2
});
```

Just be sure to inject `$location` in your controller/directive.

Comment: why the vote down? I can improve if I know what's wrong

Comment: Because the OP specifically stated he was looking for an alternative to the approach you suggested.

Comment: @MikeFeltman he said "I would like to use a querystring parameter if it's possible"